# Infer generic type arguments from nested generics

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, type-inference

I came up with a generic function `foo` that chains two generic functions while catching an generic Exception and returning a generic. However I cannot invoke it. The types and arguments might be a bit confusing here, but using more verbose names here is not any less confusing.

Function `bar` should supply all generic types to infer them, but it shows a compile error and I cannot explicitly add them either (`execute<E, Class<D>, D, IOException>(...)` results in 'not applicable for the arguments').

I have tried wrapping my head around it for some hours now and using `fooBar` compiles without a problem. So I guess there is no problem with the type compatibility but rather how I invoke `foo` in `bar` or how they are inferred.

```
public class A {
    // similiar to BiFunction but throws Exception
    static interface Foo<P1, P2, R> { R apply(P1 p1, P2 p2) throws Exception; }
    static class Bar extends RuntimeException { /*...*/ }

    public static <R1, D1, R2, E1 extends Exception> R2 foo(Foo<B, C, R1> arg1, C arg2, BiFunction<R1, Class<D1>, R2> arg3, Class<E1> arg4, Class<D1> arg5) {
        try {
            B b1 = new B();
            R1 r1 = arg1.apply(b1, arg2);
            return arg3.apply(r1, arg5);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            if (arg4.isInstance(e1)) {
                return null;
            }
            throw new Bar();
        }
    }

    public static D bar() {
        Foo<B, C, E> foo1 = (b1, c1) -> b1.foo(c1); // where B.foo(C) returns E
        BiFunction<E, Class<D>, D> bar1 = (e1, cClass) -> e1.bar(cClass); // where E.bar(Class<D>) returns D
        return foo(foo1, new C(), bar1, new IOException(), new D()); // compile error: cannot infer generic type arguments
    }

    public static D fooBar() {
        Foo<B, C, E> foo1 = (b1, c1) -> b1.foo(c1); // where B.foo(C) returns E
        BiFunction<E, Class<D>, D> bar1 = (e1, cClass) -> e1.bar(cClass); // where E.bar(Class<D>) returns D
        try {
            B b1 = new B();
            E e1 = foo1.apply(b1, new C());
            return bar1.apply(e1, D.class);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            if (IOException.class.isInstance(e1)) {
                return null;
            }
            throw new Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

This took infinitely long to paste and format, I am sorry if I mistyped anything. **How can I invoke `foo`so the generic type arguments are inferred?**

Comment: I think you should take some time and make sure that this code has no trivial errors, for example first method does not have a return type.

Comment: @michalk right, I missed an `R2` while typewriting, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo`'s fourth and fifth parameters expect `Class`es, but you are giving it an `IOException` and a `D`.

You probably meant to give it `IOException.class` and `D.class`:

```
return foo(foo1, new C(), bar1, IOException.class, D.class);
```